# how to use multiple js controllers in aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i have created a lightning component and app where 5 boxes are displayed, my requirement is that "Whenever i click on that single boxes color should change to red and it should display a text called "Booked", and again when i click on that same box it should turn to green and text should show up named "Available"
how do i achive this, 
i have put the code below, please help me out

```
<aura:component >
    <p>  Floor No 0 </p>
<button id="btn" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"  style="color:black; background-color:green" onclick="{!c.handleButtonChange}">1 BHK Available</button>
<button id="btn1" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"  style="color:black; background-color:green" onclick="{!c.handleButtonChange1}">2 BHK Available</button>
```

js controller

```
({
    handleButtonChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var button_text = document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML;
        //alert(button_text);
        if(button_text=="Available") {
            document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "Booked";
            document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "Available";
            document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor = "Green";
        }

    }
})

({
    handleButtonChange1 : function(component, event, helper) {
        var button_text = document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML;
       alert(button_text);
        if(button_text=="Available") {
            document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "Booked";
            document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "Available";
            document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "Green";
        }
    }
})
```

in the output - color should change and text from available to booked

Comment: i forgot to add the component - <aura:component >
    <p>  Floor No 0 </p>
<button id="btn" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"  style="color:black; background-color:green" onclick="{!c.handleButtonChange}">1 BHK Available</button>
<button id="btn1" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"  style="color:black; background-color:green" onclick="{!c.handleButtonChange1}">2 BHK Available</button>     </aura:component>

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean `booked` and use `aura:if` to implement this functionality. Also you can use `themes` for getting green or red buttons.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" access = "GLOBAL">

    <aura:attribute name="booked" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.booked}">
        <lightning:button label="Available" onclick="{!c.doBooked}" class="slds-theme_success" />
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.booked}">
        <lightning:button label="Booked" onclick="{!c.doAvailable}" class="slds-theme_error" />
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({  
    doAvailable: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.booked",false);
    },
    doBooked: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.booked",true);
    }    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 (using lightning:button)**

Component

```html
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="label" type="String" default="Available"/>

    <lightning:button onclick="{!c.handleClickAction}" label="{!v.label}" variant="{!v.label == 'Available' ? 'success' : 'destructive'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```js
({
    handleClickAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.label', component.get('v.label') === 'Available' ? 'Booked' : 'Available');
    }
})
```

**Option 2 (using lightning:buttonStateful)**

Component

```html
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="buttonstate" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <lightning:buttonStateful
            labelWhenOff="Available"
            labelWhenOn="Booked"
            labelWhenHover="Unbook"
            iconNameWhenOff="utility:add"
            iconNameWhenOn="utility:check"
            iconNameWhenHover="utility:close"
            state="{!v.buttonstate}"
            variant="{!v.buttonstate ? 'destructive' : 'success'}"
            onclick="{!c.handleClickAction}"
    />
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```js
({
    handleClickAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.buttonstate', !component.get('v.buttonstate'));
    }
})
```